# How to hide desktop icons by double clicking the desktop using c#

Tags: c#, desktop, icons, double-click

I wanted to know if there is a way to toggle desktop icon to show/hide when the desktop is double clicked. Similar to how it is done in Stardock Fences. I wanted it to be done using visual c#.

Answer (score 2):

The second part of your question (when the desktop is double-clicked) is relative simple. You need to install an application-defined hook procedure into a hook chain. Sounds pretty difficult, but is explained in detail in the code sample found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx). You may want to download the source [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook/globalhook2_src.zip) (requires a free account there).

For the first part, the hiding/unhiding of desktop icons, I found several similar code samples like [this](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/828132-c-hide-desktop-icons), however, none seem to work on my pc so you might want to look for another solution to that problem.

Comment: you're right, the last link doesn't seem to work, but thanks anyway for the first 2 links.

Answer (score 0):

For hiding the desktop icons there is a registry key (have a look [here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/RegistryTips/Disable-Hide/HideDesktopIcons.html)).

I guess you will have to restart your explorer after that to apply the changes by using

```
        Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Explorer");
        foreach(Process p in proc)
            p.Kill();

        Process.Start("explorer.exe");
```

Comment: using that registry hack will permanently hide the desktop icons. I wanted it to be toggled to show/hide.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know how you would show/hide the desktop icons using C#, however i have read a few articles about how to do it using the resistry keys. the problem with using the registry keys method is that the "Explorer.exe" process would have to be restarted in order for the changes to take affect. luckily i found a code sample online that does just that:

```
On Error Resume Next

' Kill Explorer.exe

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'explorer.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
objProcess.Terminate(1)
Next

' Launch Explorer.exe

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 

objShell.Run "explorer.exe" 

Set objShell = Nothing

Wscript.exit
```

That script will quickly restart the "Explorer.exe" process without logging the current user off.... Hope it Helps!